# Android : error: failed linking references

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Am getting error while trying to build the application.

```
Android resource linking failed
 error: resource style/Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light (aka 
 com.xxx.xxxx/Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light) not found.
 error: failed linking references.
```

**build.gradle**
    compileSdkVersion 28

also in sdk manager platform tools for 28 is installed

but am not getting the cause of this issue

**style.xml**

```
**<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/card_bg</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black_dim</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/cursorColor</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeChange" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTabLayoutTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/tab_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: show your `style.xml`

Comment: @ NullPointerException edited by adding style

Comment: Have you use any support libraries and extend your Activity with AppCompatActivity?

Answer (score 1):

I am new in coding of any kind, but I have just fixed this error by following a solution in another StackOverflow thread that says to do the following:

Give in the command

```
gradlew.bat --info clean build
```

I gave this command into the end of my `build.gradle` file and it showed me AS WELL as fixed the error!

I'm so happy! This command should be the answer to many problems!